# EJS for loop with Sqlite DB

Tags: node.js, sqlite, ejs

I really need help for my project. I need to connect my databank with ejs and a for loop. My Code of the ejs-site:

<% for (var i =0; i <=daten.length;  i++ ) { %> 
<%=daten%>
<% } %>

Then I go to my Website, I only recive as answer "[object,Object]. One of my headlines I want to show is "Name", but whenever I write daten.Name, my Website is broken.
Can someone help me here?

Comment: Whatever `daten` is, it looks like it's array-like, which means that you possibly want `<%= daten[i] %>`.